# How can I reverse a deletion in LibreOffice Writer Track Changes mode?

Tags: libreoffice

In *Track Changes* mode of LibreOffice Writer, you can propose the deletion of a word by using backspace until the word is completely crossed-out.

I expected that, if I do this again, I can undo this deletion. But pressing backspace again does not reverse the deletion.

[image]

Comment: Ctrl+z will undo the deletion right away. If at a later stage you want to go back to the deleted word and undo the the deletion, you can right-click it and choose "cancel change" (not sure of the exact English text here).

Comment: It is called `Reject Change`. Thank you! That is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either:

- press Ctrl+z to undo the deletion right away; or
- at a later stage, right-click on the deleted word and choose "Reject Change".